# QueueTriggerAttribute Missing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function using the `3.0.0-beta8` version of the  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions`, `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Core` and the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` NuGet packages, and it does not resolve the `QueueTriggerAttribute` package - has this been deprecated / moved to a new library?

It is not immediately apparent what I install to use this trigger in an Azure Function.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have met the [breaking change](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) in new function runtime.

> The Azure Storage bindings (blob, queues and tables triggers and bindings) were previously part of the runtime, but moving forward, will need to be explicitly installed.

Solution is to install this package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` `3.0.0-beta8`. For v2 functions, note that we should always install [package of the latest version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need) in Nuget.

Also make sure your runtime version is the latest. Check this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363).

Comment: Thanks - I suppose I could have worked that out but `.Storage` didn't seem to fit the bill for queue triggers.

Comment: Wow, such a helpful comment I found almost 3 years later :) So many tutorials don't seem to note this.

Comment: Within the context of azure, storage includes queues, blobs, and tables @DenverCoder9

Comment: This is unbelievable. Feature is dead on arrival in VS 2022, still broken.

Comment: This fixes in VS2022. Current version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage is (5.1.0) as of 2/23/2023